# What should be used, $v=r \omega$ or radial and transverse components? What would be the next step?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

An aircraft A is flying in a vertical plane containing two tracking stations P and Q which are 15km apart. At a cetain instant θ (measured anticlockqise from horizontal line PQ to the line PA) is 60° and the $ \dot \theta $ (angular velocity) is -0.025rad/s. At the same time, α (measured anticlockqise from extended horizontal line PQ to the line QA) is 150° and the $\dot \alpha$ is -0.02rad/s. Determine the magnitude and the direction of the velocity of the aircraft.

I used the radial and transverse components of the velocities relative to P and Q and calculated the resultant.

Relative to P, radial component = $$\frac{d(PA)}{dt}= \frac{d(15000Cos(\theta))}{dt} = -15000Sin(\theta) \dot \theta $$

The transverse component = $$r \dot \theta =-(PA)0.025$$

The components of velocity relative to Q could be obtained in the same way but I'm not sure about what to do next. Is taking the resultant of them correct? I took the resultant and got the following answers.

Magnitude - 15133m/s

Direction - 88.89° north of east

Comment: **definite** duplicate of [How could this problem be solved? Using general $r \omega$ or by using radial and transverse components?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/126010/)

Comment: Hi S.Dan. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Answer (score 0):

If you draw the figure, the vectors $\vec{PA}$ and $\vec {QA}$ are orthogonal.    The triangle is $30-60-90$ so you can find the length of $PA$ and $PQ$.  The observed $\dot \theta$s give you the projection of the airplane velocity on these two axes.  Add these two projections to get the total velocity.